# Referencia de objetos utilizando el operador spread como asignación mediante un valor prederteminado

Tags: javascript, funciones, operador

Por qué el objeto X actualiza el objeto VALUE, si el operador spread genera una copia sin referencia?

```js
const value = { number: 10 };

const multiply = (x = { ...value }) => {
  console.log((x.number *= 2));
};

multiply();
multiply();
multiply(value);
multiply(value);

//20,20,20,40
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que no estás usando el spread para crear un nuevo objeto con tu parámetro... lo que estás haciendo con esa sintaxis es darle un valor por defecto al parámetro usando el objeto `value` que has creado antes! Si quieres crear un nuevo objeto para trabajar con él debes hacerlo en el cuerpo de tu función, no en el atributo!

```js
// Para demostrarlo vamos a renombrar la variable a obj
const obj = { number: 10 };

// Y ahora el código da error en esta línea porque "value" no está definido!!
// Estabas asignando un valor por defecto!!
const multiply = (x = { ...value }) => {
  console.log((x.number *= 2));
};

multiply();
multiply();
multiply(obj);
multiply(obj);
```

Para hacer el spread de manera correcta, lo hacemos DENTRO DEL CUERPO DE LA FUNCIÓN:

```js
const value = { number: 10 };

// Si quieres mantener el valor por defecto puedes
// Recuerda, esta asignación x = value NO ESTA REALIZANDOSE SI PASAMOS UN PARÁMETRO NOSOTROS!!
// Solo significa que SI NO PASAS PARÁMETRO, cogerá ese valor por defecto!
const multiply = (x = value) => {
  // Ahora creamos el nuevo objeto usando el spread
  const newObj = {...x};
  console.log((newObj.number *= 2));
};

// Y dado que lo primero que hacemos en un método es crearnos un nuevo objeto para trabajar
// el original NUNCA cambia!
multiply();
multiply();
multiply(value);
multiply(value);

//20,20,20,20
```

TLDR:

Si la llamabas sin pasarle parámetro estabas usando spread para asignar una nueva copia del objeto `value` por defecto, así que el valor de X no cambiaba, pero si la llamabas pasándole un parámetro en ningún momento se usaba el spread, puesto que lo tenías puesto como valor por defecto, y ese código nunca se ejecuta si tú le pasas un parámetro!! Recuerda, **la lógica nunca va en los parámetros**!